# Angularjs login authentication issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new using Angularjs and I'm building a login-page using AngularJS through REST API. I'm facing an issue when I am trying to submit my form. I browsed through so many web-site and links, but I din't got proper answer. Please don't tell me to google it, because I already have so many blue links. If you know anything , please correct me and if you have any working example share it .

AngularJS :

```
var app = angular.module('logapp',['toastr','ngRoute']);    
app.factory('Auth', function($http){
    var service = {};

    service.login = function(username,password) {
    $http.post('http://localhost:3000/loginfo',
    {
        username : username,
        password : password
    })
    .then(
        function successCallback(response){
            console.log(response.data);
        });
    };

    service.isAuthenticated = function() {
        return {
        isAuthenticated : false,
        }
    };

    return service;
    });

app.controller('credientials', function($scope,$http,Auth) {
$scope.isAuthenticated = false;

$scope.userCred = {
username: '',
password: ''
}

/*-----Form Submition-----*/

$scope.log = function(userCred){

Auth.login(userCred, function(result) {
console.log(Auth);
if (result === true) {
    console.log('success');
} else {
    $scope.Error = response.message;
}
});
};
```

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: I am getting **Auth.login** is undefined and in my factory , server is not matching the user input data

Answer (score 0):

First things first, this part

```
Auth.login(userCred, function(result) {
```

is Wrong. Your `service.login` takes 2 parameters. And they are username and password. It does not take any callback.

Right way to do it is like this

```
Auth.login(userCred.username, userCred.password)
  .then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Which goes without saying, you refactor your `service.login` as follows

```
service.login = function(username,password) {
  return $http.post('http://localhost:3000/loginfo',{
    username : username,
    password : password
  })
}
```

Comment: I implemented your code in my server, but i got Auth.login is undefined

Comment: My server is just posting its data to my json file when user gives any random input and it's not matching the content